# @Host() without <ng-content> in Angular2 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-decorator, angular2-ngcontent

I'm trying to limit the search of my dependencies to only its host by using `@Host`.

But it's not working without `ng-content` or transclusion.

**The below code is not working(without ng-content)**

```
// Root Component
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<parent></parent>'
    })
    export class RootComponent { }


    @Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<child></child>',
    providers:[{provide:TestService,useClass:TestService}]

   })
   export class ParentComponent {
    name: string = '';
    constructor(abc:TestService){
        abc.name='SomeName';
        this.name=abc.name
       }
    }

    @Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<h1>{{parent}}</h1>'
    })
         export class ChildComponent {
    parent: string = ""
    constructor(@Host() testService: TestService) {
        this.parent= 'My parent is :'+testService.name;
      }
    }
```

**With ng-content**
Now just by changing the templates in `RootComponent` & the `ParentComponent` the above code starts working

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<parent><child></child></parent>'
    })
    export class RootComponent { }

 @Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
    providers:[{provide:TestService,useClass:TestService}]

   })
   export class ParentComponent {
    name: string = '';
    constructor(abc:TestService){
        abc.name='SomeName';
        this.name=abc.name
       }
    }

    @Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<h1>{{parent}}</h1>'
    })
         export class ChildComponent {
    parent: string = ""
    constructor(@Host() testService: TestService) {
        this.parent= 'My parent is :'+testService.name;
      }
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. Why the first code not working(without ng-content)..?
2. @Host can only works with ng-content..?
3. What difference ng-content makes as the structure of the compiled HTML is same in both the cases.

**Here are the Plunker for reference:**

[Not working](https://plnkr.co/edit/grhiGmtmivbK9W4uBtAA?p=preview)

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: `providers:[{provide:TestService,useClass:TestService}]` is the same as `providers:[TestService]`

Comment: Not able to get the reference of TestService in the first example where @host is used without content projection...though the child has a host

Comment: Please provide a Plunker

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use `viewProviders` instead of `providers` to work with `@Host` as also shown in [@Host](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Host-decorator.html)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wgVhygyrP1hGvaGudVya?p=preview)

Comment: I don't know. I never used `@Host()` myself (or it is so long ago that I don't remember)